# lightswitch automatic refetch of entity after updated

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In a mssql database a trigger is updating a field in a table after some other field from the same row is being updated. In a lightswitch application after the update is executed the values updated by the trigger are not shown automatically in the screen, only after hitting the refresh button they are shown. What would be the most efficient way to accomplish that after updating the entity is  refetched, without having to call the refresh button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would not use the trigger.

If you must use the trigger, you can call .Refresh() on the Entity programatically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael. In our case we are not in a green field project, we have to live with the triggers. Isn't the refresh fetching all enities in the given screen? Is it possible to get only the particular entity being updated?

Comment: You can create a query that is constrained to only particular records and call .Refresh() on that query.

Answer (score 0):

This code enables you to auto refresh queries after any given time interval

http://www.lightswitchspecial.com/2012/02/autorefresh-lightswitch-screen.html?m=1

Might be of use